# Does the Druid spell Wall of Lava have to be connected to an actual wall or ground?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, druid

Does the Druid spell Wall of Lava need to be connected to the ground or a wall? Or, can it be cast in mid air, such as in front of a flying creature?

Answer (score 8):

## Yes, it has to be on the ground

*Wall of lava* is a Conjuration spell, and there are [general rules](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Conjuration) for conjuration spells:

> A creature or object brought into being or transported to your location by a conjuration spell cannot appear inside another creature or object, nor can it appear floating in an empty space. It must arrive in an open location on a surface capable of supporting it.